# Flex Bitmapimage tooltip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5, bitmapimage

I am using Bitmapimage in my code.After a lot of seach on google i could not find How tooltip can be used with Bitmapimage.Any suggestion will be appreiciated.
Thanks in advace!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your BitmapImage in a Group and set the tooltip for the Group. Tooltip is indeed a property of UIComponents so it works with many Flex components but not BitmapImage...